# Android SDK manager does not show packages to be installed

Tags: android, sdk

I have installed Android SDK and packages. Since I had an error when opening a new project on Eclipse, I decided to uninstall SDK and install again. The problem now is that I am not seeing the packages to install, I can only see Android SDK tools.

How can I re-install it and see all the packages?

Comment: Have you already installed the SDK Tools and Platform Tools?  The individual packages won't show up until you have those two pieces in place.

Comment: I have only an installation file called "installer_r20-windows.exe"

Comment: Perhaps you could share a screenshot of what your manager currently looks like.

Comment: Well, I was about to take screenshot when the packages appeared again, as I expected in the very beginning.I am installing it right now, I hope there will be no surprises this time. Thanks for your time, Devunwired!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem now is that I am not seeing the packages to install, I can only see Android SDK tools.

Install that package first, and all the others will then appear (you may need to restart the manager).

Comment: It is already installed, eventhough I have uninstalled the whole SDK and installed it again

Answer (score 47):

For everyone who got this problem:
Open SDK Manager click tools in the top menu -> options and turn on
**force hِttps://...sources**

Comment: This definitely fixed it for me. I was only able to see the Google APIs, but now I can see the SDK Platform and everything else in the Android SDK Manager.

Comment: this helped, it was making me crazy!!

Comment: This should definitely be the accepted answer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: it worked for me too! definitely should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: Nice, I couldn't see the Extras. Disabling https solved it. Too bad it had to be disabled.

Comment: Saved the day for me!

Comment: For some reason I'm not seeing a top menu in the SDK manager; anyone know how to do this in v2.2.3?

Comment: Update: I think I found the same checkbox on the 3rd tab "SDK Update Sites". Unfortunatley, I think I already had the platform-tools downloaded and still can't access the "adb" command.

Answer (score 6):

I also got the same issue when i run my SDK i was getting nothing but android SDK tools & Extras without any branches. Proxy which i was using was not allowing SDK manager to download all the items.

- Open SDK Manager
  Tool -> options -> Give the proxy settings
  Packages -> Reload

Above 3 steps reloaded all the package which i was longing to see for 2 days :).

If not for all atleast for few folks this might help

Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 6):

For those already having this problem:
You maybe should change proxy settings.

I test the proxy settings inside the SDK Manager Tool. But not helpful.

- Open Java Control Panel inside control panel
- Change proxy settings under Network Settings

Comment: thank you so much..you saved my day; I checked in settings, the proxy was set to my college's configuration

Answer (score 3):

I use VPN software, so in Android Studio I went to *Default Settings -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy* and checked *Auto-detect proxy settings*. It works for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Mac: go to Android SDK MANAGER -> Preferences -> "Force http ..."

Answer (score 0):

Still  not  find any suitable answer ?

Go to Package -> mark as selected all top three package

✓ 1-show updates/New Package

✓ 2-show installed package

✓ 3-show obsolete package

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Tools > Options > Clear Cache, then Packages > Reload, all from the SDK Manager window.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, right click SDK Manager in `android-sdk` home directory and `Run as administrator`. That solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Run SDK Manager as an Administrator.**

Do the following 2 Steps

1. Right click on SDK Manager.
2. select run as an Administrator.

Comment: Is this all the steps? please improve the answer by writing the number of steps and enumerating each on their own line.

Answer (score 0):

To everyone having this issue, I was able to fix it by installing the required dependencies through the terminal with:

sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-i386 lib32z1 default-jdk.

After that, all the other API packages showed up

Answer (score 0):

Use VPN to connect google servers and fetching packages

Answer (score 0):

in new version of android studio go to Tools-> sdk tools-> android sdk-> sdk update site, add this repository https://dl.google.com/android/repository