# Not showing installattion options for Android SDK

Tags: android, android-install-apk, android-sdk-tools

I had installed Android SDK but that was not installed correctly and I could not create an Android project in Eclipse, so I uninstalled, re-installed the Android SDK manager but I can't see all the options. The window I'm watching now is this:
[image]

Note: Its my first day with Android and I want to create my first "Hello world" example, but don't know what's wrong with the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314359/android-sdk-manager-does-not-show-packages-to-be-installed) it is already discussed. please review this question answers

enjoy :)